# Funcion If en R

Tags: r

Me ha surgido una duda y quisiera compartirla para ver si alguien puede ayudarme.
Estoy trabajando en R con una matriz llamada `matriz_diferencia`. La misma tiene 3 filas de las cuales una esta vacía y 96 columnas. Lo que intento hacer, es ir completando esa tercera fila con valores que surgen de un condicional. Si el valor de la segunda fila es `<0`, el valor debería ser `0`, de lo contrario seria:

```
(matriz_diferencia[2,x] - matriz_diferencia[1,x]) / matriz_diferencia[1,x]
```

He encontrado la forma de hacerlo utilizando un for y un if:

```
for(x in 1:96) {
    if(matriz_diferencia[2,x]<0) {
        matriz_diferencia[3,x]=0
    } else {
        matriz_diferencia[3,x]<-(matriz_diferencia[2,x] - 
            matriz_diferencia[1,x]) / matriz_diferencia[1,x]}
}
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente: 
¿Cómo podría hacerse esto mismo utilizando la función apply? 
¿Existe alguna otra alternativa para no utilizar for?

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, armamos un ejemplo más chico que el tuyo, solo para fines didácticos:

```
set.seed(1)
matriz_diferencia <- matrix(c(rnorm(2 * 4 ), rep(0, 4)), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
matriz_diferencia

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286 1.5952808
[2,]  0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.4874291 0.7383247
[3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
```

En este caso no es necesario pasar por un ciclo, R está "acostumbrado" a trabajar con vectores y matrices, lo que hace las cosas mucho más sencillas en ese sentido.

Buscamos actualizar la tercer fila con dos criterios ditintos, una forma es no preocuparse por el `if` y actualizar directamente en dos pasos, el primero, aplicando el calculo que has dado y en el segundo ponemos en cero aquellos casos donde el valor de la fila 2 sea menor a cero:

```
matriz_diferencia[3, ] <- (matriz_diferencia[2,] - matriz_diferencia[1,]) / matriz_diferencia[1,]
matriz_diferencia[3, matriz_diferencia[2,] < 0] <- 0
matriz_diferencia

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808
[2,]  0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.4874291  0.7383247
[3,] -1.5259889  0.0000000 -1.5833082 -0.5371820
```

Detalle:

- Esto: `(matriz_diferencia[2,] - matriz_diferencia[1,]) / matriz_diferencia[1,]` es aritmética con vectores que maneja naturalmente R, lo que le decimos es: suma cada "celda" de la fila 2 con cada "celda" de la fila 1 y divídelo nuevamente por los valores de la celda 1, el retorno será otro vector con los `n` valores correspondientes a cada "celda".
- La segunda pasada: `matriz_diferencia[3, matriz_diferencia[2,] < 0] <- 0` configuramos cada valor de la fila 3 en `0` si el mismo valor de la fila 2 es menor a `0`

De todas formas, si quisieras resolverlo todo en una única sentencia, podrías usar la función vectorizada `ifelse()` que trabaja directamente sobre vectores:

```
matriz_diferencia[3, ] <- ifelse(matriz_diferencia[2,] < 0,
                                 0,
                                 (matriz_diferencia[2,] - matriz_diferencia[1,]) / matriz_diferencia[1,])
```